# Projected Euclidean vs. Geodesic distances of embedded manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold embedded into $R^n$ with $g$ induced by the Euclidean distance of $R^n$ (i.e., this is an isometric embedding).

Suppose $x, y \in M$, and consider the Euclidean line segment $c(t) = (1-t)x + t y$ where $t$ is a scalar: $t \in [0..1]$. Now, define a curve $p(t) \in M$ by projecting $c(t)$ onto $M$. Thus: $p(t) = Proj_{M} (c(t)) = \arg\min_{p \in M} \|p - c(t)\|_2$.

I'm wondering if there is a relation between the geodesic on $M$ between $x$ and $y$ and the length of the curve $p(t)$ (which must lie on $M$ by definition).

Any simplifying assumptions such as $M$ being compact, without boundary and with a positive reach are OK in my context.

For example, if $M$ is a sphere, then it seems that $p(t)$ will trace the geodesic between $x$ and $y$, unless they are on the poles. Is there a characterization of this situation? Is this true locally (e.g., for $y$ in the neighborhood of $x$)? To me, it seems that $p(t)$ must provide a better estimate of the geodesic, but I cannot find relevant results. Thank you.

Comment: If you surface is more complicated, I don't see how a projection of the line to $M$ is well defined. Consider for example a torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider different positions for two points and ask yourself which curve on the torus you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just to clarify: I always assume the nearest point projection onto $M$ as mentioned in the question. I believe this is well defined outside of the medial axis ot $M$ (set of points of the ambient space for which there are multiple equidistant nearest points of the manifold).

Comment: The nearest point projection does not necessarily give you a continuous curve on $M$. If the surface bulges away from the line sufficiently quickly, the nearest point projection will jump at some point.

Comment: Yes, indeed, of course. However locally it will be continuous (in the neighborhood of $x$), so I'm wondering if anything could be said there.

Comment: For $x$ and $y$ sufficiently close, the nearest point projection will give you a continuous curve on $M$. By definition this curve is at least as long as the shortest geodesic between $x$ and $y$. I don't see any reason why this curve should be the exact geodesic unless you are in extremely special circumstances like the sphere.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I'm wondering what those circumstances are exactly. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition?